# Why when I use groupby on two columns the result is NaN but when I do it on one column it works correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I use the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': 'a a aa aa b b '.split(),
                    'item': [5,5,7,7,7,6],
                   'last_PO_code': ['103','103','103','104','103','104'],
                   'qty': [5,4,7,6,7,6]
                   })
```

and I apply this rules on it

```
regle1 = lambda x: True if x['last_PO_code'].all() == "103" else False
```

like this with one column on grouby

```
df['regle1'] = df['class'].map(df.groupby(['class']).apply(regle1))
```

I have the following result for me, it's good

```
class   item    last_PO_code    qty regle1
0   a   5       103             5   True
1   a   5       103             4   True
2   aa  7       103             7   False
3   aa  7       104             6   False
4   b   7       103             7   False
5   b   6       104             6   False
```

but when I want to groupby class and item, I have this result

```
df['regle1'] = df['class'].map(df.groupby(['class','item']).apply(regle1))

class   item    last_PO_code    qty regle1
0   a   5       103             5   NaN
1   a   5       103             4   NaN
2   aa  7       103             7   NaN
3   aa  7       104             6   NaN
4   b   7       103             7   NaN
5   b   6       104             6   NaN
```

someone can help me to understand please ??

Comment: When you `groupby` two columns your resulting Index is now a MultiIndex. This means that when you just `map` the class column there are no matches because your index is really tuples (class, item). Instead you should `merge` the result back so that it matches on both class and item, or you could use `groupby` + `transform` to broadcast the result back to the correct rows

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you're looking for groupby+transform, but trying to implement that via `pd.Series.map`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': 'a a aa aa b b '.split(),
                    'item': [5,5,7,7,7,6],
                   'last_PO_code': ['103','103','103','104','103','104'],
                   'qty': [5,4,7,6,7,6]
                   })
def regle1(x):
  return (x == '103').all()

df['regle1'] = df.groupby(['class', 'item']).last_PO_code.transform(regle1)
```

The final dataframe now looks like this:

```
  class  item last_PO_code  qty  regle1
0     a     5          103    5    True
1     a     5          103    4    True
2    aa     7          103    7   False
3    aa     7          104    6   False
4     b     7          103    7    True
5     b     6          104    6   False
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it helps a lot, now my problem is that I can't find the equivalent for the function eq() 
for my second rule

`
`regle2 = lambda x: x.loc[x['last_PO_code'].eq('103'), 'qty'].sum() > x.loc[x['last_PO_code'].eq('104'), 'qty'].sum()
`

Comment: @LyèsSARDI, could you make that its own question please, with all details attached, as in sample data, what you tried, what you expect etc.